# JSF: How programmatically force clearing of the Facelets cache (so can trigger from a button) in a Glassfish web app

Tags: jsf, caching, jsf-2, glassfish, facelets

*This question is spawned from [Mac: JSF: why are development stage JSF web apps not always catching composite component changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680986/mac-jsf-why-are-development-stage-jsf-web-apps-not-always-catching-composite-c?noredirect=1#comment59321756_35680986). If I can answer the question here, I will have a brute-force strategy for getting around that other reported problem, but this question here has a standalone purpose.*

Q: How can I programmatically force clearing of the Facelets in-memory cache in a running web app (so that I can create a listener that is invoked from a [Clear Facelets Cache] button) ?

I am using NetBeans8.1beta and Glassfish4.1, with deployment over the NetBeans project's /build/web.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this by now?

Comment: @Roben No solution yet, and still very interested in finding one. Webel

Comment: Maybe this will be possible using a custom facelet cache factory. See the answer from Ballusc on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984924/custom-faceletfactory-in-jsf-2-2-alternatives-for-virtual-host-facelets. Thanks to seam, I am still stuck with JSF 2.1 though, so I am currently not able to test this.