# How to override DefaultFaceletFactory in JSF 2.2.8-

Tags: jsf-2.2, faces-config

I want to choose different facelet cache based on url like -

```
        if url starts with some pattern - Choose Nocache
        otherwise - Choose default cache - expiringConcurrentcache
```

I am trying to override the DefaultFaceletFactory but my class is not getting triggered.

I think I need to give some configuration in faces-config.xml or web.xml but I am not sure what I am missing. I am using JSF 2.2.8.

Does anyone know what's the configuration I am missing?

```
public class DynamicFaceletFactory extends DefaultFaceletFactory {

    @Override
    public Facelet getFacelet(FacesContext context, URL url) throws 
                     IOException {
        if (url.getPath().contains("include://dynamicComponent/?uniqueId=")) {
            DefaultFaceletCache noCache = new DefaultFaceletCache(0); //noCache
            return noCache.getFacelet(url);
        } else {
            return super.getFacelet(context, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FaceletsFactory != FaceletsCacheFactory. Sure you don't want to override the FaceletsCacheFactory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984924/custom-faceletfactory-in-jsf-2-2-alternatives-for-virtual-host-facelets

Comment: I do not have access to the URL inside the FaceletCacheFactory. I am not sure how to decide the kind of cache.

    public class DynamicFaceletFactory extends FaceletCacheFactory {

     @Override
     public FaceletCache getFaceletCache() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
     }

    }

Comment: Ok, me neither and I have no time to find out the coming days. I'm out camping with a phone but without laptop